# After installing Xcode 7 I can't build and run projects anymore as document fails to open

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

EDIT: This question refers to teh pre-release version of Xcode 7, hence it may not be relevant if you are running the currently released version as some issues may have been fixed.

---

I get the following:

> Failed to connect with the iOS agent. Please file a bug report at
>   bugreport.apple.com.

[image]

Why is that?

If I look at the details I get:

> =================================
>
> ## ERROR:
>
> Failed to find or create execution context for description
>    System content
>   1x for IBCocoaTouchFramework-EightAndLater w/ default fidelity
>   (Failure reason: Software caused connection abort): Failed to find
>   newest available Simulator runtime (Failure reason: Software caused
>   connection abort): Simulator verification failed. (Failure reason: A
>   connection to the simulator verification service could not be
>   established.)
>
> Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 "Failed to find or create
>   execution context for description
>    System content
>   1x for IBCocoaTouchFramework-EightAndLater w/ default fidelity"
>   UserInfo=0x7fcf5961ebd0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to find or
>   create execution context for description
>    System content
>   1x for IBCocoaTouchFramework-EightAndLater w/ default fidelity,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x7fcf58b72950 "Failed to find newest available
>   Simulator runtime"}

Comment: Xcode 7 is in beta, and you shouldn't use it for normal development. Try to report the bug to apple.
If you need Xcode 7 because you wanted to test your project with Swift 2, then try to create a new project, and import files manually.

Comment: How do u do iOS 9 development then? Can it be done on XCode 6?

Comment: If you need to use Swift 2.0, and any iOS9 new API, then you must use Xcode 7. But if you only want to make an app for a build target below 9, you should use Xcode 6 for dev and build. It is possible to build from Xcode 6 to an iOS9 device (sometime it doesn't want to, but I can build for my iOS 9 phone).

The point is Xcode 7 is still very buggy, it's a beta. So it's not so much reliable so far. You may use it for iOS9 and swift 2 testing, but I wouldn't advice to use it for any other purposes. I think it will be more reliable with the next betas, coming this summer

Comment: Interesting fact : Since beta 2, it is NOT possible to install Xcode 6.x on Mac OS 10.11 El Capitan

Comment: @Dean You still can run it https://github.com/zenangst/Zcode

Comment: Is there any other way ? I tried all of below but no luck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure which answer to accept as for me what worked was installing a later beta (beta 5). I had filed a bug to Apple a couple of months ago so I assume they solved this problem by updating Xcode.

Anyone experiencing this with the current official release?

I post this as answer for now but if anyone has a more detailed explanation I will be happy to remove my answer and accept yours.

Comment: i have this bug 7.0.1 release version

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue with xcode 7 beta 3.

I had my deployment target set to 8.3. Setting it to 9.0, cleaning the build, and restarting xcode worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting and reinstalling your Xcode beta, it worked for me on Xcode beta 3

Comment: I deleted and reinstalled my beta 2 (now I will with beta 3). I did so by dragging XCode to the bin and empty it and then re-install it. Any other raccomended way to delete it completely?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is a common issue. Found an answer over at Apple's developer forums:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11706

In case the link goes dead or you have no access, this is the accepted answer:

> **Correct Answer by seancook on Jul 21, 2015 5:58 PM**
>
> I experienced this, too, on El Capitan. NIBs wouldn't load, no Sims
>   present, and unable to launch Simulators through the Xcode/Open
>   Developer Tool/Simulator menu. After fighting it for a few hours I've
>   finally got it working.   Here's what worked for me (YMMV):   I
>   noticed a message in Console.app along the lines of the Simulator
>   runtime not being code signed. I went to the path it described
>   "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes" and removed the
>   runtimes that I had there. They were old runtimes, so I assume that
>   some check in Xcode now applies that didn't previously. Who knows?
>   After doing this, I could *finally* launch the Simulator via the
>   Xcode/Open Developer Tool menu. Unfortunately, the Simulator still
>   wasn't being shown as a run target in my workspace, so I kept
>   spelunking...   I then went into the Simulator's
>   Hardware/Devices/Manage Devices menu and added a new iOS9 device. It
>   didn't seem to do anything, so I quit out of Xcode and Simulator.app.
>   I then re-started Simulator.app (via Xcode/ODT/Simulator) and lo and
>   behold the expected iOS9 simulators were displayed.   I closed and
>   re-opened Xcode, changed the target OS for my project, and the Sims
>   were finally displayed as run targets.
>
> HTH.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error on with Xcode 7.0 release build (7A220). I was running on device too not using the simulator at all.

I did a full clean *Clean build folder...* option, close Xcode and then opened up Activity Monitor. I found a bunch of **Ibtool** processes running. I terminated all of these and restart Xcode.

All going again!

Answer (score 0):

Verify you have the latest Xcode Beta installation with Xcode-beta open click "About Xcode" and check the build number.

Then check the Current build number of the latest Xcode-beta on the Xcode Downloads Page:

https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your stack trace does not show anything relevant with the answer which I found, however, my stack trace also seemed me irrelevant. But it worked for me and hope that works for you:

Someone from Apple staff gave the answer at:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3978

What was said is "We saw this in the labs at WWDC. The crash was caused by an offending custom color picker. Try removing any custom color pickers you have installed on your system"

In brief, delete related color picker from your system, close the xcode and relaunch.

Answer (score 0):

Another things I would check it's what command line you are using.

I had to use a different version and I changed them with :

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode8.app/Contents/Developer/
```

( You can also change it in the XCode/Preferences/Location )

I think my problem was that I was using the version 8.1

You can see the comand line you are using with:

```
xcode-select -p
```