# Xcode 7 cannot open xib files

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, xcode7

After installing Xcode 7 i am not able to open xib files. It says that failed to connect with iOS Agent. Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com

I have tried reinstalling Xcode but it doesn't work

Any idea ?

Comment: see this link may be help with you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138430/after-installing-xcode-7-i-cant-build-and-run-projects-anymore-as-document-fail

Comment: This problem is just on your system, on my system xcode 7 is working fine, please try to remove xcode and remove all preference file then reinstall