# Build Error in Xcode 11.3.1 - IBCocoaTouchFramework-ThirteenAndLater

Tags: ios, xcode

I am having following error every single time I try to build an app in Xcode 11.3.1 on macOS Catalina 10.15.3. I see this error for UIKit as well as SwiftUI based projects. Xcode fails to load storyboard file (or scene) and fails to build

```
/<PATH TO PROJECT>/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard:1:1: 
Failed to find or create execution context for description '<IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: 0x7fd283181f90> System content for IBCocoaTouchFramework-ThirteenAndLater <IBScaleFactorDeviceTypeDescription: 0x7fd283187160> scaleFactor=2x'.
```

Please note, this error is not specific to `LaunchScreen.storyboard` file. I have tried not having launch screen and instead straight `Main.storyboard` but nothing works.

I have tried everything else including rebooting my mac, killing Simulator process deleting Derived Data. All these steps, a few of these steps but cannot get rid of it. My Xcode is plagued with this issue and I cannot build any project.

If you have encountered this issue, please share what you did to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533720/failed-to-find-or-create-execution-context-for-description-ibcocoatouchplatform ?

Comment: In theory, possibly a duplicate but all versions are newer now including `ThirteenAndLater` in error string itself and none of the solutions there worked. That's why I reposted as new.

Comment: Well, reinstalling Xcode fixed it for me.

Comment: @matt: agreed. sorry, did not see your comment. I voted to close this issue. You may want to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, reinstalling Xcode fixed it for me.